# How to move non-rectangular objects in Pygame?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, shapes

In my game, *Battle Ship*, I am trying to move the ship when the arrow keys are pressed. My ship comprises a five-sided polygon and five lines bordering it. I have scoured the net for ways to move it, but am only finding ways to make rectangle- and square-ships move. The following is my code (without any attempts at moving the ship):

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,242,0)
ship_body = (33, 117, 243)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Battle Ship")
background = pygame.image.load("Sky Background.png")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()        


    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    ship = [
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, ship_body,((100,50),(180,95),(320,95),(400,50),(250,35))),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (100,50),(180,95),1),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (180,95),(320,95),1),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (320,95),(400,50),1),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (400,50),(250,35),1),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (250,35),(100,50),1),
            ]

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure in Pygame you can draw those lines to a new surface, then simply blit it to wherever you want it to go. That's the best method IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of points for the polygon and increment and decrement them:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,242,0)
ship_body = (33, 117, 243)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Battle Ship")
#background = pygame.image.load("Sky Background.png")

pygame.key.set_repeat(50,50)

ship_points = [ [100, 50], [180, 95], [320, 95], [400, 50], [250,35] ] 
x = 0
y = 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()        

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: 
               x = -1

           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: 
               x = 1

           if event.key == pygame.K_UP: 
               y = -1

           if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: 
               y = 1

           for point in ship_points:
                point[0] += x
                point[1] += y

           x=0
           y=0

  #  screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, ship_body, ship_points)
    '''
    ship = [
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, ship_body,((100,50),(180,95),(320,95),(400,50),(250,35))),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (100,50),(180,95),1),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (180,95),(320,95),1),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (320,95),(400,50),1),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (400,50),(250,35),1),
            pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (250,35),(100,50),1),
            ]
    '''
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: It's working properly except for two things. I want my sky background and also my black border for the ship. How do I do that?

Comment: I commented out the background image line as I don't have the image, so just uncomment that line. Also uncomment where it is blitted and swap the order, so fill is first and blit is second. To do the movement with the border create another list with the points in it like I have for the polygon. Can't give better answer now as I am at work and on phone.

Comment: I made 5 different lists, each with two items: start and end points for the lines. Then I used your "for point in ship_points:" method, with the correct list name, and later created 5 "pygame.draw.line" commands for the border with the list names instead of X and Y coordinates for the start and end points. However, when I run the program, it says "TypeError: Invalid start position argument" for the "pygame.draw.line" line. What should I do?

Comment: Show me the draw.line code you are using, and the one of the 5 start/end points lists please, as it is hard to tell without seeing anything.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I got it. I just did it by drawing another polygon, this one with 100% transparency and a black border. I put both polygons one on top of the other and used your method to move them both. It now moves perfectly. Thank you for your time and effort! I appreciate it.